# Always return Post 400 Error jQuery on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have try to save data using ajax post but keep getting Post 400 error.
Here's my code
JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-Submit', function (e) {

        var user = {};             
            user.FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
            user.LastName = $('#LastName').val();
            user.Email = $('#Email').val();
            user.MobileNumber = $('#MobileNumber').val();
            user.LoginName = $('#LoginName').val();
            user.PassWord = $('#PassWord').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Users/Create',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { user: user },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp)
                },
                error: function () { }
            }); // ajax asynchronus request 
    });
```

Here's My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Create(User user)
    {
        try
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                user.CreatedBy = 1;
                user.UpdatedBy = 1;
                user.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Add(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
            }
            else
            {
                var error = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
        }            
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

I had thought the syntax was correct on both of these however every time I make the ajax call I get a 400 response. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you won't use `$('form').serialize()` or `$('form').serializeArray();`? Much easy and less number of code-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change you object as below and also remove **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]** because you are posting data through ajax request and it will not validate ForgeryToken.

```
var user = new {             
        FirstName = $('#FirstName').val(),
        LastName = $('#LastName').val(),
        Email = $('#Email').val(),
        MobileNumber = $('#MobileNumber').val(),
        LoginName = $('#LoginName').val(),
        PassWord = $('#PassWord').val()
        };
```

Comment: @shine  why you won't use `$('form').serialize();` or `$('form').serializeArray();`? Much easy and less number of code-line